# Call to a member function select() on a non-object

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I'm trying to retrieve some info using ajax. however when I call the `select()` method the system returns a fatal error. what is the reason for that?

here's my code:

```
     define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
     define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
     define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..' ));


     require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
     require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

     $db = JFactory::getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);
     $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'product_id')));
     $query->from($db->quoteName('sample_table'));
      // ->where('application_id = 11');


     $db->setQuery($query);
     $results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

I have used this code several times on other versions and it worked. I think it might be related to the version..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the fatal error?

Comment: Hello @BradM here's the error
 `Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object`

Comment: Try switching the order of the select and the from and see if that also is giving you an error.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code , I think you are trying to use Joomla function in external function. The error indicates that you are using the factory object without including the factory class. Try include all these files :

```
 define('_JEXEC', 1);
 define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
 define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS . '');
 require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
 require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
 require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php');

 $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 $query = $db->getQuery(true);
 $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'product_id')));
 $query->from($db->quoteName('sample_table'));
  // ->where('application_id = 11');
 $db->setQuery($query);
 $results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: not worked, faced with **Fatal error: Call to a member function select()**

Answer (score 0):

Is that all of your code? It looks to me like you have not created a database connection. You need something like

```
    jimport('joomla.database.database');
    // System configuration.
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    // Note, this will throw an exception if there is an error
    // Creating the database connection.
    $this->dbo = JDatabase::getInstance(
        array(
            'driver' => $config->get('dbtype'),
            'host' => $config->get('host'),
            'user' => $config->get('user'),
            'password' => $config->get('password'),
            'database' => $config->get('db'),
            'prefix' => $config->get('dbprefix'),
        )
    );
```

Overall with a stand alone application it takes a few more minutes the first time but I think you are better off using the API and putting it in a constructor. Here's an example https://github.com/elinw/AssetFix/blob/j3/assetfix.php#L65